# Question on finding the Laplace transform of a function that is shifted to the left

Tags: laplace-transform

Say $f$ is a function $\mathbb R_{>0}\to \mathbb C$ and $a > 0$.

Say I want to calculate the Laplace transform of $f(x + a)$.

This shifts $f$ to the left so that $f(x+a)$ is no longer zero on the negative numbers thereby violating one of the conditions necessary to calculate the Laplace transform of it.

My idea on how to work around this problem is: Multiply $f(x+a)$ with the Heaviside function.

My questions are:

1. **Is this really a possible work around or am I just making a bad mistake? It seems that $f(x)$ and $f(x+a)$ times Heaviside are no longer the same functions.**
2. **If multiplying with the Heaviside function is wrong, what is the correct way to argue that one can nevertheless calculate the Laplace transform of $f(x+a)$?**

Answer (score 1):

Not being zero on the negative numbers doesn't inherently matter, the Laplace transform restricts attention to $[0,\infty)$ by itself anyway. The problem is that some of the information about $f$ on $[0,\infty)$ has been "lost" to $[-a,0]$ and so the Laplace transform of $f(x+a)$ has no generic relationship to that of $f$. This is in contrast to $f(x-a) H(x-a)$, which has the entire graph of $f$ on $[0,\infty)$ and *only* the graph of $f$ on $[0,\infty)$, it has just been transported over to $[a,\infty)$.